# How can i get maximum rowsize in a datagrid?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, resize, rows

I'm creating a window in MVVM, it needs to show some data of the top 4 most recent records of a table in my database. All this is working fine, the only thing is that i'm supposed to stretch it out.
The 4 rows are supposed to take up all of the space. Each of them should take 25% of the view. Which is now working because i added a property, in my viewmodel the rowheight is changed to 1/4 of the viewheight. My xaml code is like this:

Now i'm trying to change the fontsize, i also added a property for that in the codebehind. And even though i change it, and i added the PropertyChanged. It won't come through, and the fontsize stays the same standard size when i look in my view. How come it doesn't change dynamically like the RowHeight?

```
<Window x:Class="MVVM_ARC_CARISTES.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVM_ARC_CARISTES"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize"
    WindowState="Maximized"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="{Binding ViewHeight, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="525">

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Unitloads}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          RowHeight="{Binding RowHeight}"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                               FontSize="{Binding FontSize, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                               TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Try putting your DataGrid in Grid

Comment: How do you mean, i can't bind an itemssource in a normal grid. Maybe if i could bind the first 4 items, to 4 different rows in a normal grid that could work. But how am i supposed to adress to those 4 items.

Comment: `<Grid>
        <DataGrid
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="10,10,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
          />
    </Grid>` , your binding stays the same. just wrap your DataGrid inside Grid Element